# Apache module development

Tags: apache, module

I'm looking to build an apache module which will be able to listen to all of the other apache modules loaded. with my module i want to know when each of the modules request handler gets called and when it ends. i want to use this for request handlers, auth handlers, filters and other modules.

Is it possible with the apache module architecture

I have looked at the mod_info and mod_example but based on my understanding there is no way to get a callback before a particular module is being called and after the module handler finished.

Is there any way to make this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get control each time the core calls into a module. You would have to modify the macros that run the hooks to instrument them in a custom httpd build.